# How to use FBX file into Blender using python script?

Tags: python, units

I need to import FBX file to blender using a python script. Does anyone know how we can do that?

Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to a particular existing script, you should post a link where one can examine it. Or you want to create a custum python script?

Comment: I am just trying a simple python script in which I have to import some images, and FBX files. I was able to import images, however, no clue how to do the same for FBX file. I have recently started exploring blender python APIs, thus my knowledge is quite limited :)

Comment: Welcome blackbug :) You have to call the operator: [**bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx()**](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.ops.import_scene.html?highlight=import_scene.fbx#bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx) Do you want to import single or multiple files? How many objects contains your fbx? In order to get a solid answer, please add more context to the question. Anyway, enjoy blender.se!

Comment: Thanks alot :) It really helped) Does same exists for importing videos as well?

Comment: Also, when I tried to import images to blender,I was able to do so, however, those images are just grey planes, I can't really see the image itself. I used "        bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane" method to do that. Any suggestions? Thanks again)

Comment: Consider that this is not a forum, asking multiple questions is not allowed here. Maybe boring, but please start with the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), edit this question, and ask a new one for importing a video via python. Thanks.